# Python: Combine two Pandas Dataframes, extend index if needed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

**How can I combine two Dataframes into one with keping all rows and all index values of both Dataframes?**

Let's say, I have two dataframes, with *partly different index values*:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 1), columns=['a'], index=[0, 2, 3, 4, 5])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5, 1), columns=['b'], index=[1, 2, 3, 4, 6])

         a
0 -1.089084
2 -0.552297
3 -0.242239
4  0.247463
5 -0.139740

          b
1 -0.407245
2  1.704591
3 -0.803438
4 -1.511515
6  0.303360
```

I want to create a new dataframe, which contains both columns with a combined index. I tried:

```
df_combine = pd.DataFrame()

df_combine['a'] = df1['a']
df_combine['b'] = df2['b']
```

which results in:

```
          a         b
0 -1.089084       NaN
2 -0.552297  1.704591
3 -0.242239 -0.803438
4  0.247463 -1.511515
5 -0.139740       NaN
```

where I would like to have, all rows & index values preserved, with NaN, if no value is available for this index value:

```
          a         b
0 -1.089084       NaN
1       NaN -0.407245
2 -0.552297  1.704591
3 -0.242239 -0.803438
4  0.247463 -1.511515
5 -0.139740       NaN
6       NaN  0.303360
```

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html

Comment: `dd = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` axis option has to be specified.

Comment: I think more idiomatic way: `df1.join(df2, how='outer')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try pandas.concat function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

```
dd = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
print(dd)
```

Output:

```
          a         b
0 -0.603074       NaN
1       NaN -0.021821
2  0.501050  0.342474
3 -2.612637 -0.256383
4  0.095779 -1.423016
5 -0.644108       NaN
6       NaN -1.756023
```

Comment: Thanks, but then I have some index-values twice. If two index values match, I want to have the column values in the same row (see desired output in my question)

Comment: They are coming in same row as shown above.

Comment: Ah, perfect! It think this the solution! :-)

Comment: Glad to be of help.